# Why distanceTo gives different results?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to get distance between two polygons and somehow I get different distance, depending on how I call distanceTo

a.distanceTo(b) != b.distanceTo(a) should it be like that?

```
layers[0].features[0].geometry.distanceTo(
    layers[0].features[1].geometry,
    {details:true,edge:true}
);
Object {distance: 10.48962511638198, x0: 2684839.287184146, y0: 7750111.194373621, x1: 2684849.7767009, y1: 7750111.146694}
```

and

```
layers[0].features[1].geometry.distanceTo(
    layers[0].features[0].geometry,
    {details:true, edge:true}
);
Object {distance: 19.05365206557588, x0: 2684857.7419808176, y0: 7749989.676176046, x1: 2684838.7291617, y1: 7749988.4294338}
```

**Some additional information...**

Main map object:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    units: 'm',
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Roadmap",
                {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, numZoomLevels: 22}
            ),
            conflictLayer,markerLayer,
        ],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(1787495.895083,  5755860.4398742),
        zoom: 18
    });
```

later I just add more layers and keep these layers in array, so 'layers[0]' is one of them.
code to generate new layer:

```
  var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(o.name, {
      styleMap: styleMap,
      renderers: renderer,
      zone_id:o.id
    });
    map.addLayer(newLayer);
    layers.push(newLayer);
```

Comment: distanceTo requires both geometries to have the same projection / spatial reference. maybe it creates the error?

Comment: You need to give us more information about the two geometries, so that we can understand and maybe explain the behaviour.

Comment: the output coordinates are not equal, x0 y0, x1 y1 for both results. Are you sure you're taking the same Points?

Comment: layers[0] is a google basemap layer and does not have vector geometries. try with layers[1] and you might get some results.